# What does line_spoken do in the program

Tags: python

Can someone please explain this program, I don't understand where role, line-spoken come from

```
>>> data = open('sketch.txt')
>>> for each_line in data: // stores each line from the sketch file in each_line
...     (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':')
...     print(role, end='')
...     print(' said: ', end='')
...     print(line_spoken, end='')
```

Comment: they're the words that came out of the split(':') operation. the file probably contains lines that look like `foo:bar`.

Comment: Each line is split on `:`. `role` is everything before it, and `line_spoken` everything after.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at a tuple assignment.

The right-hand side expression is expected to have resulted in a sequence of two elements, and these two elements are assigned to the two named targets on the left hand side.

In other words, `.split(:)` is expected to return two values, and those two values are assigned to the variables `role` and `line_spoken`. Most likely, the lines in the file contain text like `hamlet:To be or not to be, that is the question\n`.

If `each_line.split(':')` does *not* return two values, an exception will be raised instead.

Answer (score 0):

`role` and `line_spoken` are variables, which are populated with strings read from the file `sketch.txt`.  `sketch.txt` contains colon-separated pairs of words or phrases, and `role` and `line_spoken` get those words/phrases.

The `split()` function returns a ["tuple", which is "unpacked"](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html) into your two variables.

(Note that the parentheses around `(role, line_spoken)` are unnecessary.)